# Sublist on Excel

Tags: excel, list, indexing

I want to get a list in Sheet1 of the Op# of only the people in Sheet2 who are less than 2 years old.
Example showed below.
If possible, briefly comment what the formula is doing.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

I tried copying an array formula using index, small, if and row but as I don't understand what the formula is doing, I can't tweak it to my workbook.

Comment: Research the `FILTER()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula in sheet 1 `=FILTER(Sheet2!B3:B8,Sheet2!E3:E8<2)`

The first argument defines the range to return a value from and the second sets the criteria.

The formula should automatically expand vertically to to the number of rows returned from sheet2.